# websockets fails with Safari 5 but works with Chrome

Tags: safari, websocket

I am using libwebsockets and the websocket works ok with Chrome but fails with Safari.
It looks like on Safari the Establish Connection never occurs.
Looking at the header information, Safari seems to be missing a lot.

Header sent by Safari:

```
Origin: http://99.36.180.46
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: " W1278r88f939
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 99.36.180.46
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 3"3Q534h    8 042   B4
Upgrade: WebSocket 
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol:: trace-protocol
```

Header sent by Chrome:

```
   * Pragma: no-cache 
   * Origin: http://99.36.180.46 
   * Host: 99.36.180.46 
   * Sec-WebSocket-Key: dh5lUy8LU/LXX/zi/h91FQ== 
   * User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 
   * Upgrade: websocket 
   * Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame Cache-Control: no-cache 
   * Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: trace-protocol 
   * Connection: Upgrade 
   * Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you wrote a web socket server?

Comment: Yes. I wrote it in libwebsockets

Comment: I'm experience a similar issue in Safari 5.1.3. I found that Safari 5 implements an older version of the websocket protocol.

Comment: Did you find any solution?
When I tried this 
`new WebSocket( "ws://echo.websocket.org/" );`
It's successfully connected but why I typed me server address
`new WebSocket( "ws://localhost:9000/" );` then 404 error comes.

**which means error on server side & I am using Ratchet php web socket library**